# Typescript Observables http.post and http.get Handing Question

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am working on a project where I am building a simple front end in Angular (typescript) / Node to make call to a back end server for executing different tasks. These tasks take time to execute and thus need to be queued on the back end server. I solved this issue by following the following tutorial: https://github.com/realpython/flask-by-example and everything seems to work just fine.

Now I am finishing things up on the front end, where most of the code has been already written in Typescript using Angular and Rxjs. I am trying to replicate the following code in Typescript:

https://github.com/dimoreira/word-frequency/blob/master/static/main.js

This code consists of two functions, where first function "getModelSummary"(getResults in the example) calls a post method via:

```
public getModelSummary(modelSummaryParameters: ModelSummaryParameters): Observable<ModelSummary> {

        return this.http.post(`${SERVER_URL}start`, modelSummaryParameters)
            .map(res => res.json())
            ;
    }
```

to put the job in queue and assign a jobID to that function on the back end server. The second function "listenModelSummary", ideally should get executed right after the first function with the jobId as it's input and loops in a short interval checking if the job has been completed or not:

```
public listenModelSummary(jobID: string) {

    return this.http.get(`${SERVER_URL}results/` + jobID).map(
        (res) => res.json()
    );
}
```

Once the job is done, it needs to return the results, which would update the front end.

I am new to Typescript, Observables and rxjs and wanted to ask for the right way of doing this. I do not want to use javascript, but want to stick to Typescript as much as possible in my front end code stack. How can I use the first function to call the second function with it's output "jobID" and have the second function run via interval until the output comes back?

Comment: you need to subscribe. `.map(res => res.json()).subscribe(res => console.log(res))`

Comment: In my opinion, Observables really don't help you out much here. Of course you can wait until the first observable emits before calling the second function, but using promises and async/await will get you the same thing with less code.

Comment: Just noticed I made a mistake in the second block where the return output refers to another url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more reading/researching into rxjs, I was able to make my code work and I wanted to thank you guys for the feedback and to post my code below.

In my services I created two observables:

1. First one is to fetch a jobId returned by queue server:

   `// API: GET / FUNCTION /:jobID
   public getModelSummaryQueueId(modelSummaryParameters: ModelSummaryParameters): Observable<JobId>{
       return this.http.post(`${SERVER_URL}start`, modelSummaryParameters).map(
           (jobId) => jobId.json()
       )
   }`
2. Use the jobId from first segment to fetch data:

   `// API: GET / FUNCTION /:results
   public listenModelSummary(jobId: JobId): Observable <ModelSummary>{
       return this.http.get(`${SERVER_URL}results/`+ jobId).map(
           (res) => res.json()
       )
   }`
3. Below is the component that works with the 2 services above:

`

```
this.subscription = this.developmentService.getModelSummaryQueueId(this.modelSummaryParameters)
    .subscribe((jobId) => {
return this.developmentService.listenModelSummary(jobId)
    // use switchMap to pull value from observable and check if it completes
    .switchMap((modelSummary) =>
        // if value has not changed then invoke observable again else return
        modelSummary.toString() === 'Nay!'
            ? Observable.throw(console.log('...Processing Request...'))
            // ? Observable.throw(this.modelSummary = modelSummary)
            : Observable.of(modelSummary)
    )
.retryWhen((attempts) => {
    return Observable
    // specify number of attempts
        .range(1,20)
        .zip(attempts, function(i) {
            return(i);
        })
        .flatMap((res:any) => {
            // res is a counter of how many attempts
            console.log("number of attempts: ", res);
            res = 'heartbeat - ' + res
            this.getProgressBar(res);
            // this.res = res;
            // delay request
            return Observable.of(res).delay(100)
        })
})
// .subscribe(this.displayData);
// .subscribe(modelSummary => console.log(modelSummary));
.subscribe((modelSummary) => {
    console.log("FINAL RESULT: ", modelSummary)
    this.modelSummary = modelSummary;
    this.getProgressBar('Done');
});

});
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Observables are great, and are the type of object returned by Angular's HttpClient class, but sometimes, in my opinion, dealing with them is a lot more complicated than using promises.

Yes, there is a slight performance hit for the extra operation to convert the Observable to a Promise, but you get a simpler programming model.

If you need to wait for the first function to complete, and then hand the returned value to another function, you can do:

```
async getModelSummary(modelSummaryParameters: ModelSummaryParameters): Promise<ModelSummary> {
  return this.http.post(`${SERVER_URL}start`, modelSummaryParameters).toPromise();
}

async doStuff(): Promise<void> {
  const modelSummary = await this.getModelSummary(params);

  // not sure if you need to assign this to your viewmodel,
  // what's returned, etc
  this.listenModelSummary(modelSummary)
}
```

If you're dead-set on using Observables, I would suggest using the concatMap pattern, which would go something like this:

```
doStuff(modelSummaryParameters: ModelSummaryParameters): Observable<ModelSummary> {
  return this.http
             .post(`${SERVER_URL}start`, modelSummaryParameters)
             .pipe(
               concatMap(modelSummary => <Observable<ModelSummary>> this.listenModelSummary(modelSummary))
             );
}
```

Here's an article on different mapping solutions for Observables: https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293 that might help you out.

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't quote me on that concatMap pattern, that's just some pseudo-code to give you an idea of what's involved compared to the async/await method. From a performance standpoint, I think you'll find these are probably only a few milliseconds apart. Observables will always be slightly faster because they're performing one less operation (at least)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
getModelSummary(modelSummaryParameters: ModelSummaryParameters): Promise<ModelSummary> {
  return this.http.post(`${SERVER_URL}start`, modelSummaryParameters).toPromise();
}

async someMethodInYourComponent() {
  const modelSummary = await this.get(modelSummary(params);
  this.listenModelSummary(modelSummary)
}

// OR
someMethodInYourComponent() {
  this.get(modelSummary(params).then(() => {
    this.listenModelSummary(modelSummary);
  });
}
```